# When is image frame from Logitech C920 USB webcam decoded by UWP MediaFrameReader

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

Where does decompression (decoding) happen when an image frame from my Logitech C920 USB webcam is received by the MediaFrameReader.FrameArrived Event of my Windows 10 UWP .NET C# app?

Is frame from camera decoded before the MediaFrameReader.FrameArrived Event or when I call sender.TryAcquireLatestFrame()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is frame from camera decoded before the MediaFrameReader.FrameArrived Event or when I call sender.TryAcquireLatestFrame()?

For this question, you could refer [Camera Frames](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraFrames) code sample. From the code point of view. The decompression (decoding) happen before `FrameArrived`.

```
private void FrameReader_FrameArrived(MediaFrameReader sender, MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs args)
{
    // TryAcquireLatestFrame will return the latest frame that has not yet been acquired.
    // This can return null if there is no such frame, or if the reader is not in the
    // "Started" state. The latter can occur if a FrameArrived event was in flight
    // when the reader was stopped.
    using (var frame = sender.TryAcquireLatestFrame())
    {
        if (frame != null)
        {
            var renderer = _frameRenderers[frame.SourceKind];
            renderer.ProcessFrame(frame);
        }
    }
}
```

Because the frame has [contained](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CameraFrames/cs/FrameRenderer.cs#L123) `SoftwareBitmap`.It means that the original data has been decoded then packaged as frame instance.

Comment: Encoding is PNG or JPG?